# How to change text color for parts of text that are between two placeholders?

Tags: java, android, spannablestring

I have a **TextView** that may contain a text that number of placeholder is unknown.
I need to change the color between all two pairs of <> (for some reason i can't add the 'B' letter between <> so please consider that in every place i'm writing <> a 'B' is existed between the brackets.
For example, for the following string:**"I  twenty <>years<> old"** -> the text should be with red color beside the parts between <> (am, years) that should be in blue color.
The problem is that i can't know how much times the <> pairs is existed in the String.

Comment: I feel like `SpannableString` would suit your requirement. Also, please edit the question with your code!

Comment: @Vishnu, i don't have code because i don't know how to get the indexes for the part of the sentence that should be replaced. I know that SpannableString can help me to color the text, but again can't find the indexes since i don't know the amount of <> appearances

Comment: Oh, then I think you can loop through the `String`, find the indices that matches a `<`, then check for a `>`, get it's index and colorize the text in-between. Continue this step till end of the `String`. I can show this in code if you can post the current code.

Comment: @Vishnu thank you, but unfortunately I can’t write anything since it too hard for me. Thanks anyway

Comment: Too hard?! Okay, post some piece of code like where this is used or on which context this should be implemented etc. I'll try to make it a working solution and post it here :)

Comment: If I will show the context I will expose my company feature. It’s a big problem for me. If you can’t help it’s ok and I am appericiate your will